# Java Objects and Methods

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how does objects works on Java with a  Automatic Transmission vehicles program. I have one method to increase the speed of the car `speedIncrease` and another to get the speed of a current object `currentSpeed`. On my test case, I created on `TransmissionBox` object called `renault` with an initial speed of `25`. The `speedUp` method increase the speed by two so the new speed should be 27. Seems that the object is loosing all the modifications after his fist invocation. How can it be possible?

**test: set up**

```
  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    private TransmissionBox renault;
    renault = new TransmissionBox(25,10,20,30,40,50);
  }
```

**test: speed = 27**

```
  @Test
  public void speedIncrease(){
   assertEquals(27,renault.speedUp().currentSpeed());
  }
```

**test: speed = 25**

```
  @Test
  public void speedIncrease(){
   renault.speedUp();
   assertEquals(25,renault.currentSpeed());
  }


**TransmissionBox class**

public class TransmissionBox {
private int speed;
private int gear;
private int threesholdOne;
private int threesholdTwo;
private int threesholdThree;
private int threesholdFour;
private int threesholdFive;



  public TransmissionBox(int iniSpeed, int iniThresholdOne, int iniThresholdTwo, int iniThresholdThree, int iniThresholdFour, int iniThresholdFive){
      this.speed = iniSpeed;
      this.threesholdOne = iniThresholdOne;
      this.threesholdTwo = iniThresholdTwo;
      this.threesholdThree = iniThresholdThree;
      this.threesholdFour = iniThresholdFour;
      this.threesholdFive = iniThresholdFive;

      if(speed == 0 && speed < threesholdOne){
        this.gear = 1;
      }

    else if(speed > threesholdOne && speed < threesholdTwo){
      this.gear = 2;
    }

    else if(speed > threesholdTwo && speed < threesholdThree){
        this.gear = 3;
    }

    else if(speed > threesholdThree && speed < threesholdFour){
        this.gear = 4;
    }

    else{
        this.gear = 5;
    }

  }


  public TransmissionBox speedUp(){
    TransmissionBox fasterCar = new TransmissionBox(speed+2, threesholdOne, threesholdTwo, threesholdThree, threesholdFour, threesholdFive);
    return fasterCar;
  }

  public TransmissionBox speedDown(){
    TransmissionBox slowerCar = new TransmissionBox(speed-2, threesholdOne, threesholdTwo, threesholdThree, threesholdFour, threesholdFive);
    return slowerCar;
  }

  public int currentSpeed(){
    return this.speed;
  }

  public int currentGear(){
    return this.gear;
  }


  public String toString(){
    return "speed: " + this.speed + "\n gear: " + this.gear;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the object is loosing all the modifications after his fist invocation"?  Which test is failing?

Comment: @Test
  public void speedIncrease(){
   renault.speedUp();
   assertEquals(25,renault.currentSpeed());
  }

Comment: Why the result is 25 and not 27 since I already increased the speed ?

Comment: That code **doesn't compile**, because you cannot have a `private` field *inside* a method!!! Please provide *valid* [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you call speedUp() in the wrong test

Comment: I am calling speedUp() in the two different tests and I got different results

Comment: you are calling speedUp() and then asserting 25. in the other test you assert 27 without speeding up. shouldn't it be the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

Notice what you do here:

```
renault.speedUp();
assertEquals(25,renault.currentSpeed());
```

What happens when you call `speedUp()`?  This does:

```
TransmissionBox fasterCar = new TransmissionBox(speed+2, threesholdOne, threesholdTwo, threesholdThree, threesholdFour, threesholdFive);
return fasterCar;
```

The *existing* object is unchanged, and a *new* object is returned.  Basically, the current car didn't "speed up" at all.  You just got into a new faster car.

But what do you do with that new returned object?  Nothing:

```
renault.speedUp();
```

The `renault` object is unchanged, and the new returned object is ignored/discarded.  The `renault` is still going 25 as designed.

If you want `speedUp()` to affect the current car, modify the current object instead of returning a new one:

```
public void speedUp(){
    this.speed += 2;
}
```

Note that this no longer returns an object.  Unless you really need it to, the semantics of that flow don't really make sense.  (Not *everything* needs to be a fluent interface.)  So this test would need to change:

```
@Test
public void speedIncrease(){
    assertEquals(27,renault.speedUp().currentSpeed());
}
```

To something like this:

```
@Test
public void speedIncrease(){
    renault.speedUp();
    assertEquals(27,renault.currentSpeed());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much David! I totally got it now! I thought my first approch was more "Object Oriented" but it makes sense!